# jquery datatables editable how to make cell 'read only' after editing?

Tags: datatables

I am using jquery-datatables-editable plugin with jQuery DataTables successfully. Is there a way to make editable cells UN-editable *after* they have been edited?

Basically I have a table with a checkbox, and once it is checked it needs to be uneditable. I am assuming this would be a 'fnOnCellUpdated' parameter or maybe part of a rowcallback function?

Comment: Even if anyone going to answer that, a link to your plugin is necessary.. also it would be better if you provide some samples from your code

Comment: I am thinking there has to be a way to turn off editability using a function in fnRowCallback when the row is redrawn after an update, OR maybe using "fnOnCellUpdated:" in the "aoColumns" section. I know I can manipulate the cell data this way, or change a class or id, etc, but as far as changing whether the cell is editable or not?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like an idiot. It really is simpler than I thought:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
    var shop_ok_data = aData[15];
    if(shop_ok_data == "checked"){
        $('td:eq(10)', nRow).addClass("read_only");
    }
    return nRow;
},
```